# How to use curl in gitlab-ci file?

Tags: curl, gitlab-ci

In my gitlab-ci file, I want to use the command `curl` to get the result of a page and verify its content, but I don't know how to use it.

```
....................
server:check-quality:
  <<: *all-settings
  stage: check-quality
  <<: *tags_definition
  script:
  - echo "APPEL de CURL"
  - content=($curl http://example.com/sonar/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=com.orange.catalog:feature-m752-conditionequals)
  - echo "content"
  - exit 0
  only:
  - develop
  - /^feature.*$/
  - /^hotfix.*$/
```

Have you any idea please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In script you can use curl like

```
script:
  - echo "APPEL de CURL"
  - curl http://example.com/sonar/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=com.orange.catalog:feature-m752-conditionequals
  - echo "content"
  - exit 0
```

Answer (score 24):

I'm not so sure this would work; as the YAML interpreter will gobble up various special characters, such as the : in that http. To make it work after hours of struggling this is the solution I found.

```
    - |
      curl --fail --output "/dev/null" --silent --show-error --write-out "HTTP response: ${http_code}\n\n" \
        --data "{\"tag_name\": \"${CI_COMMIT_TAG}\", \"name\": \"${CI_PROJECT_NAME} ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}\", \"description\": \"${CI_COMMIT_TAG_MESSAGE:-No release notes.}\"}" \
        --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --header "Private-Token: ${CI_PRIVATE_TOKEN}" \
        --request POST \
        "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/releases"
```

This script will generate a release using the gitlab api, so a little more fancyfull then what you are requesting.

Note, that CI_COMMIT_TAG_MESSAGE is my variable, which will hopefully be added to GitLab.

The biggest problem was figuring out all the special characters that need escaping.

Also, you swapped your ( and $ in your content parameter ;)

Comment: in my case i have to put `curl -X POST "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/releases" \ --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${CI_PRIVATE_TOKEN}" ...` and the rest is ok

Comment: and the next thing i've noticed right now is http instead of https at the begging

Answer (score 22):

This is how to use `curl` in GitLab CI YAML script with no hassle in 2021.

The following example CI pipeline uses `curl` to trigger the remote application build and deploy on Digital Ocean App Platform for the real use case sake.

Here `curl` uses URL arguments from [GitLab variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) and passes a JSON body with the request:

```yaml
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    DEPLOY_CURL_COMMAND_BODY: "'{\"force_build\":true}'"
    DEPLOY_CURL_COMMAND: 'curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $DO_APP_PLATFORM_API_TOKEN" --data $DEPLOY_CURL_COMMAND_BODY https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/apps/$DO_APP_PLATFORM_STAGE_FRONT_APP_ID/deployments'
  script:
    # The following echoes are just a debug output
    - echo "Stage Deploy to DigitalOcean App Platform"
    - echo "$DO_APP_PLATFORM_API_TOKEN"
    - echo "$DO_APP_PLATFORM_STAGE_FRONT_APP_ID"
    - echo $DEPLOY_CURL_COMMAND
    # This line actually executes curl command saved within the variable.
    - 'eval "$DEPLOY_CURL_COMMAND"'
```

The pipeline puts a command's argument into a variable. Then `eval` the variable. Note the single quotes wrapping the variable value and `eval` command. They are principal.

The variable uses as well the extrapolated [repository level variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#define-a-cicd-variable-in-the-ui) for secrets (namely `DO_APP_PLATFORM_API_TOKEN`, `DO_APP_PLATFORM_STAGE_FRONT_APP_ID`).

Note that GitLab YAML does not complain about a lone `:` colon sign. It complains about `:`  - a colon followed by space sign. So the above example is universally applicable for both cases. But simpler implementation as per [@Mavichow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66013243/6597265) answer would serve well when there is no space after colon in the command line.

Note as well that you can use curl `body` parameter that requires being wrapped in single quotas itself. Note there is no space after comma in `body` variable content.

Some other ways to avoid `:`  (colon followed by space) issues:

```bash
  after_script:
    # Note how the single quotes eliminate colon+space issue
    - 'MESSAGE="Tests finished with status: ${CI_JOB_STATUS}"'
    # Here pipe operator allows using colon+space on the next line
    - |
      curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "{\"text\":\"$MESSAGE\"}" "$SOME_URL"
```

Comment: "Note that GitLab YAML does not complain about a lone : colon sign. It complains about : " was the key for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can use | (multiline script) to bypass this like:

```
....................
server:check-quality:
  <<: *all-settings
  stage: check-quality
  <<: *tags_definition
  script:
  - echo "APPEL de CURL"
  - |
    content=($curl http://example.com/sonar/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=com.orange.catalog:feature-m752-conditionequals)
  - echo "content"
  - exit 0
  only:
  - develop
  - /^feature.*$/
  - /^hotfix.*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modify some workaround and CURL with variable and works for me with below scripts:

```
testing:
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - curl --request GET --header "Authorization:cpanel user:$CPANEL_API_TOKEN" "$CPANEL_URL/execute/VersionControl/update?repository_root=%2Fhome%2Ftesting%2Fpublic_html%2Ftesting.domain.com&branch=master"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official Gitlab docs about curl in script : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html

> Sometimes, script commands must be wrapped in single or double quotes. For example, commands that contain a colon (:) must be wrapped in single quotes ('). The YAML parser needs to interpret the text as a string rather than a “key: value” pair.

You must sometimes use single quotes.