# How to get list of the files in a folder in gitlab-ci

Tags: shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create a pipeline in gitlab-ci. my problem is that when I run ls command I can see my files, but when I use for condition, I cannot find same files. any suggestion?

```
  script:
    - set -vux
    - ls ./dist/*
    - |
      for file in ./dist/*; do 
          if [ -f  ${file} ]; then 
              export ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG=${DATASCIENCE_REPO}/$(basename ${file})/$IMAGE_VERSION
              'curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: $ARTIFACTORY_PW" -XPUT "$ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG" -T dist/$file'
          fi 
      done
  dependencies:
    - package-build
```

my output is like this:

```
$ ls ./dist/*
ls ./dist/*
++ ls ./dist/__init__.py ./dist/my_proj-0.0.1.1164649-py3-none-any.whl ./dist/file1.py ./dist/file2.py ./dist/file3.json ./dist/file4.json
./dist/__init__.py
./dist/my_proj-0.0.1.1164649-py3-none-any.whl
./dist/file1.py
./dist/file2.py
./dist/file3.json
./dist/file4.json
echo $'\x1b[32;1m$ for file in ./dist/*; do  # collapsed multi-line command\x1b[0;m'
++ echo '$ for file in ./dist/*; do  # collapsed multi-line command'
$ for file in ./dist/*; do  # collapsed multi-line command
for file in ./dist/*; do 
    if [ -f  ${file} ]; then 
        export ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG=${MY_REPO}/$(basename ${file})/$IMAGE_VERSION
        'curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: $ARTIFACTORY_PW" -XPUT "$ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG" -T dist/$file'
    fi 
done
++ for file in ./dist/*
++ '[' -f ./dist/__init__.py ']'
+++ basename ./dist/__init__.py
++ export ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG=https://artifactory.xyz.com/artifactory/my_proj_dev/__init__.py/0.0.1.1164649
++ ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG=https://artifactory.xyz.com/artifactory/my_proj_dev/__init__.py/0.0.1.1164649
++ 'curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: $ARTIFACTORY_PW" -XPUT "$ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG" -T dist/$file'
/scripts-11718-6374270/step_script: line 239: curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: $ARTIFACTORY_PW" -XPUT "$ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG" -T dist/$file: No such file or directory
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Update 1: according to the error I am receiving, I think in my curl command system cannot file the file. but why I am not sure?

Comment: Why are there single quotes around the _entire_ curl command?! You’re trying to run a command called `curl -H …`. Remove the single quotes. You should probably have more double quotes here and there, though. [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) can help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simple syntax mistake.

**The error says there is `No such file or directory`.**

```
line 239: curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: $ARTIFACTORY_PW" -XPUT "$ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG" -T dist/$file: No such file or directory
```

## An experiment.

Let's run these three commands in your terminal.

## The first one

(**DO NOT REMOVE A SINGLE QUOTE.**)

```
'touch love and peace'
```

The result is in `bash`

```
-bash: touch love and peace: command not found
```

The result is in `zsh`

```
zsh: command not found: touch love and peace
```

**A terminal recognizes the single-quoted string as a command in the first command**.

## The second one

(**DO NOT REMOVE A SINGLE QUOTE.**)

```
'touch /'
```

The result is in `bash`

```
-bash: touch /: No such file or directory
```

The result is in `zsh`

```
zsh: no such file or directory: touch /
```

**A terminal recognizes the single-quoted string with the slash as a file in the second command**.

## The third one

without a single quote.

```
touch love and peace
```

The result is

```
$ls
and  love  peace
```

## If you intend to run the `curl` command in every loops,

Just remove the single quotes.

```
curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: $ARTIFACTORY_PW" -XPUT "$ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG" -T $file
```

The solution

```
      for file in ./dist/*; do 
          if [ -f  ${file} ]; then 
              export ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG=${DATASCIENCE_REPO}/$(basename ${file})/$IMAGE_VERSION
              curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: $ARTIFACTORY_PW" -XPUT "$ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG" -T $file
          fi 
      done
```

Comment: Thanks I think your point can be correct, but I dont remember why I was require to put single qoute for curl command which could be due to some space in my details that problem will resolve by doube qoutation which you mentions. also in the last line of curl no need to put "dist/" because $file contains the dist/ as well. I will test your solution tomorrow and keep you posted. please fix the last line and if it work tomorrow I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Amir Thank you for helping me to improve my answer. I searched to know [when a curl command is quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790984/how-to-use-curl-in-gitlab-ci-file). It seems when curl is assigned to a [variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68723482/20307768). In other cases like a script, a curl command won't be quoted. So in your script, curl doesn't need to be quoted.

Comment: Also, the [variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68723482/20307768) shows that `eval` is used to use the variable as a command.

Comment: Thank you @Constantin, I tested your suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like the problem is that you are not listing the files in your `for` statement. Try:

```bash
for file in `ls ./dist/*`; do
    echo "act on $file" 
done
```

Comment: I think the problem is not with the loop, btw ur code also giving the same result. I tested and curl also exists. I tried to change the object path to '-T ./dist/${file}' but again same result...
++ 'curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: $ARTIFACTORY_PW" -XPUT "$ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG" -T ./dist/${file}'
/scripts-11718-6374633/step_script: line 241: curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: $ARTIFACTORY_PW" -XPUT "$ARTIFACTORY_IMAGE_TAG" -T ./dist/${file}: No such file or directory

Comment: This is a bad answer; it’s [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (and it’s using backticks). There’s nothing wrong with OP’s way of iterating files.

Comment: You are correct. I did not correctly read the whole `curl` command, which is where the real issue was.